# shopping cart confirmed order database

Tags: database, oracle, jsp

i am not able to understand how can manipulate multiple confirmed order with single order-id in database..

i just want to know what elements should i add to the table 
currently i am setting the values like this.

```
order_id    username   product_ids
1234455      abc        01,03,05
```

but by this i am not able to get the quantity of products and i am not getting how can i implement this
since i am storing the product-id at the time of retrival at checkout page . so when user updates the quantity it doesnt get stored any where so can any one tell me how to interact with qunatity and use it in the order table

```
<div id="load">
            <div style="font-size: 30px; margin-left: 40px; border-bottom: 2px">
                <img
                    src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/4c9/5pe/4c95peMcE.jpeg"
                    height="40px" width="40px" />
                <th>MY SHOPPING BAG</th>
            </div>
            <br>
            <%
                Iterator it = null;
                String id;
                ArrayList list = new ArrayList(); //for collection of confirmed products
                id = request.getParameter("id");
                String username = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute(
                        "sessionusername");
                Test tt = new Test();
                it = tt.Buy(username);
            %><table id="mytable">

                <%
                    int i = 0;
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        i++;
                        Product_List PL = (Product_List) it.next();

                        list.add("" + PL.getProduct_id());
                        String order = list.toString();
                        session.setAttribute("orders", order);
                %><tr class="row">



                    <td class="delete">
                        <div class="centererer">
                            <form action="PDelete" method="get">
                                <input type="hidden" name="p_id" value="<%=PL.getProduct_id()%>"
                                    id="Product_id" /> <input type="submit" class="close" value="x">
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="image"><img src="<%=PL.getImage()%>" width="86"
                        height="86" /></td>
                    <td class="name"><%=PL.getBrand()%> <%=PL.getDetail()%></td>
                    <td class="size"><%=PL.getCloth_size()%></td>
                    <td class="pricexx">&#8377;</td>
                    <td class="price"><%=PL.getPrice()%></td>
                    <td class="quauntity">
                    <select class="quantityx">
            <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>


                        </td>
                    <%!int totalprice, netprice = 0,quant=1;%>
                    <%
                        totalprice = quant * PL.getPrice();
                    %>
                    <%
                        netprice = totalprice + netprice;
                    %>

                    <td class="pricexx">&#8377;</td>
                    <td class="price" id="tp"><%=PL.getPrice()%></td>
                </tr>
                <%
                    }
                %>
            </table>
            <!--         -->
            <input type="hidden" value="<%=list.toString()%>" name="array" /> <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <!-- <td  class="size"></td> -->
                    <td class="total">TOTAL <span class="pricex">&#8377;</span><span class="pricex" id="np"><%=netprice%></span></td>


                </tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suggesting you to use two tables for this.

1. Order Master Table (OrderMast)

   ```
   order_id    username     order_date
   1234455      abc         03/05/2014
   ```
2. Order detail table (OrderDetail)

   ```
   order_id    product_ids    product_Qty    time of retrival
   1234455       01              10           21:01:00 pm
   1234455       03              12           21:02:00 pm
   1234455       05              20           21:04:00 pm
   ```

using inner joins you can select data as you wish.

```sql
 SELECT pm.Order_id,
        pd.Product_qty
 FROM OrderMast pm
 INNER JOIN OrderDetail pd 
 ON pm.Order_id  = pd.Order_id.
```

Comment: i thought of the same thing but avoided it because of multiple order-id in 2nd table.. is there any better option ??? and if i am using it though than how can forward quantity along with product-id

Comment: could you please tell me the exact result set /  Final user interface with quantities, that you need to show to your users.